# Уточните, пожалуйста, правильную пунктуацию в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "Екатерина провела переговоры с партнером, и было принято решение о закрытии проекта" правильно ли поставлена запятая?
Это сложносочиненное предложение без общей придаточной части, поэтому запятая нужна, но возможно есть исключение.

Comment: Если это отдельное предложение, то скорее всего да, обычное СПП, самый первый пример - https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/obshchaya-harakteristika-slozhnosochinennyh-predlozhenij?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2F